# iphone application's container

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I'm trying to figure out how to build an iPhone application which will have a set of applications to download and use. An example of this is "pogo games" application, where you can download new games. 
I thought of using "In-app Purchase" to achieve this, but apple wouldn't let me offer those apps for free, would they?
Any thoughts and ideas on how to do this will be very wellcome!

Answer (score 0):

In-app purchases cannot be free. But an in-app purchase would only be useful to unlock downloaded or built-in content anyway. So if you want to offer free downloads, just offer them.

If you intend for this to be in the app store, do be aware of the App Store Review Guidelines 2.7 and 2.8:

- 2.7 Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected
- 2.8 Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected

You would have to convince Apple that your downloads are data only and contain no code, or face rejection.